# Retrieve JSON from Firebase with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, alamofire

This is my code:

```
let urlWithId = url + buildingInfo.building.identifier + ".json"
Alamofire.request(urlWithId).responseJSON{ (response) in
    print(response.result.value)
}
```

When printing value of type Any?, I get this:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x123456789012>(
<null>,
{
    aaa = 111;
    bbb = "bbb";
    ccc = 000;
    ddd = "ddd";
    eee =     (
        a,
        b,
        c
    );
}
)
)
```

This is supposed to work, but always returns nil:

```
if let value = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
    // Never gets into here, always nil
}
```

I want to get a JSON:

- **aaa**: unsigned long
- **bbb**: string
- **ccc**: unsigned long
- **ddd**: string
- **eee**: json

If I do the request in Safari, I get this:

```
[
    null,
    {
        "aaa":111,
        "bbb":"bbb",
        "ccc":000,
        "ddd":"ddd",
        "eee":[
                  "a",
                  "b",
                  "c"
              ]
    }
]
```

Any idea? Maybe another way of requesting json with Firebase URL

Comment: You have a problem with the database firebase,
Please add screenshot of your database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see the JSON response, you are not getting dictionary rather you are getting array. And your needed response in at index `1`. So parse as:

> **In your response JSON array:**
>
> index 0 = null
>
> index 1 = array

**Update your code as:**

```
if let value = response.result.value as? [Any], let dict = value[1] as? [String: Any] {
    print(dict)
}
```

Comment: ["aaa": 111, "bbb": bbb, "ccc": 000, "eee": <__NSArrayI 0x604000256980>(
a,
b,
c
)
, "ddd": ddd]

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                    debugPrint("\n Success: \(data)")
            case .failure(let error):
                debugPrint("\n Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
```

Comment: "\n Success: (\n    \"<null>\",\n        {\n        aaa = 111;\n        bbb = \"bbb\";\n        ccc = 111;\n        ddd = \"ddd\";\n        eee =         (\n            a,\n            b,\n            c\n        );\n    }\n)"